# Assertion in postman to check date format

Tags: testing, postman

I need to check a **mm/dd** format in an assertion in postman when i have a response to a birthday information.
In the body i have the following response

> ```
> "birthday:{"month_day":"07-21", "year":"1962"}
> ```

how could i check in my test with pm.response that the response month_day has a mm-dd value?
thanks in advance

Comment: Is the the response data? `"birthday:{"month_day":"07-21", "year":"1962"}`

Comment: yes is part of the body, now i need to add an assertion in test to validate that format is like MM-DD or transform and validate that all is like yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really quick and horrible check could be this:

```
pm.test('Check the date format', () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json().birthday
    pm.expect(`${jsonData.month_day}-${jsonData.year}`).to.match(/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As postman supports moment.js lib, you can make assertion like this (that's old postman syntax):

```
var moment = require('moment');
let response = JSON.parse(responseBody);  
tests["date format is valid"]=moment(new Date(response.birthday.month_day)).format("MM-DD") == response.birthday.month_day;
```